# How to avoid NullPointerException in Drools if in the 'when' clause are managed values that might be null?

Tags: java, drools

I've the following Drools rule code:

```
rule "S001_EVENT_Date 2023-02-02 03:01:01.901 +02"
    when 
        // EventRequest(info.timeStamp.equals("2023-02-02 03:01:01.901 +02"));
    
        EventRequest(info.timeStamp != null)  
        && 
        EventRequest(info.timeStamp.equals("2023-02-02 03:01:01.901 +02"));
    then
        // set("S001",15);
        // log(drools,"1st Event rule!");

        System.out.println("1st event rule!");
end
```

The first commented out line issues, obviously, a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when info.timeStamp, that is of class `String`, is `null`.

I've tried the solution in the lines following the commented out, but the same exception still occurs.

How I've to solve this problem?

I'm understanding that drools doesn't manage conditions as Java do or I've misunderstood the drools syntax.

Comment: Not sure why you're being down-voted. The question is perfectly understandable from a Drools perspective.

Comment: I think there's someone that hates me!!! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the method `equals` you can use `==` to do the string comparison. In Drools, this will do an implicit null check. I'm presuming, of course, that `info.timestamp` is a String.

eg.

```
EventRequest( info.timestamp == "2023-02-02 03:01:01.901 +02")
```

Obviously if this were Java you shouldn't be comparing strings with `==`, but this is Drools.

That being said, you can always do a null check like you showed in your example. Your example isn't the best because it won't work as you expect it should should there be multiple EventRequest instances in working memory; the following would be the more appropriate constructions:

```
EventRequest( info.timestamp != null,
              info.timestamp =="2023-02-02 03:01:01.901 +02" )
```

This requires that both conditions (the null check and the equality) happen on the *same* EventRequest instance; the `,` is an "and".

Alternatively, if the issue is that `info` is what is actually null, you can clearly check for that as well.

```
EventRequest( $info: info != null )
Info( timestamp != null,
      timestamp =="2023-02-02 03:01:01.901 +02" ) from $info
```

How many null checks are actually needed depends greatly on what the model actually looks like, but there's no real penalty in defensive coding on the left hand side ("when" clause), which the Drools engine will optimize anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative that what Roddy wrote is to use the null-safe dereference operator supported by drools: `!.`:

```
rule "S001_EVENT_Date 2023-02-02 03:01:01.901 +02"
    when 
        EventRequest(info!.timeStamp != null)  
        && 
        EventRequest(info!.timeStamp.equals("2023-02-02 03:01:01.901 +02"));
    then
        // set("S001",15);
        // log(drools,"1st Event rule!");

        System.out.println("1st event rule!");
end
```

More information about this operator can be found in the [Drools Documentation](https://docs.drools.org/8.41.0.Final/drools-docs/drools/language-reference/index.html#ref-drl-operators_drl-rules)

Comment: That still doesn't necessarily work if there are multiple EventRequests in working memory, since the && doesn't require both conditions be applies to the same instance and the equals may be applied to one with a null timestamp after the null check is satisfied by a different instance. But good point on the null-safe dereference operator -- I always forget about that.

Comment: Now I just read what I had written (something I guess I should do before posting :P), and I think the first pattern can be completely removed. You could just leave `EventRequest(info!.timeStamp == "2023-02-02 03:01:01.901 +02")`

Comment: Yep that would do the trick.